# React Native with Expo app not rendering FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have no errors showing but I am getting a blank page when my app runs. It started rendering a blank page when started putting some api code which I copied and pasted from another project where it worked exactly perfect but for some reason, it is refusing to work here This is how my code looks like. This is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import Screen from './app/components/Screen'
import ProductScreen from './app/screens/ProductScreen';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <Screen>
      <ProductScreen />
    </Screen>
  )
}
```

Then this is the product screen.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import Card from '../components/Card';

export default function ProductScreen() {
    const [products, setproducts] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);

    const getProducts = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1');
            const data = await response.json();
            setproducts(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong in your code",error)
        } finally {
            setloading(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
           {loading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
               <FlatList
                   data={products}
                   keyExtractor={(id) => id}
                   renderItem={({item}) => (
                       <Card 
                           title={item.title}
                           subtitle={item.description}
                           img={item.image}
                       />
                   )}
               />
           )}
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

And lastly the card.js file

```
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import AppText from './AppText';

export default function Card({title, subtitle, img}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={img} style={styles.image} />
            <View style={styles.cardText}>
                <AppText style={{color: "black"}}>{title}</AppText>
                <AppText style={{color: "#4ecdc4"}}>{subtitle}</AppText>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are several issues in your [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@vuyi/spontaneous-candy). First your expression of:

```
{loading && <FlatList />}
```

is wrong because you're setting it to check for loading of `true` when after you retrieve your data in `getProducts` you set it to `false`.

Was able to get it to work, again, with:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import Card from '../components/Card'

export default function ProductScreen() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/5')
      const data = await response.json()
      setProducts([data])
      setLoading(false)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Something went wrong in your code', error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts()
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!loading && products.length !== 0 && (
        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={products}
            keyExtractor={(_, id) => id.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Card title={item.title} subtitle={item.description} img={item.image} />}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    flex: 1,
  },
})
```

Another error exists in `Card` for `Image`. Per memory when passing an image URL it should be set with a URI:

```
<Image source={{ uri: img }} style={styles.image} />
```

Another issue you'll face is in `ProductScreen` the `View` style for `container` should have a `flex: 1` applied as indicated in the code above.

Comment: I removed the finally and set the setloading(false) like you did and it still does the same thing. And when I console. log the data it returns the item requested from the api.

Comment: on my phone give me a minute and I'll test with an expo snack

Comment: @DARTHVADER sure

Comment: I just tried on the expo snack all the edits you made and it's still the same thing blank page I don't know how you were able to render out anything. When you rendered the stuff out, Was the page styled? as in with colors, borders, spacing etc?. This is my expo the one with your edits https://snack.expo.dev/@vuyi/spontaneous-candy Oh and thanks for taking the time out to help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I ran it locally from `expo init`. Just learning React Native but let me look into it. I think it's something to do with the `FlatList` and how the data is brought in.

Comment: @DARTHVADER thanks bro it's finally working funny how its such small issues but thanks again I appreciate the help‍

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code for [snack.expo.dev/@vuyi/spontaneous-candy](https://snack.expo.dev/@vuyi/spontaneous-candy) it seems your missing the conditional rendering in your return for the ProductScreen.

Your code looks like this:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
           {loading &&
               <FlatList
                   data={[products]}
                   keyExtractor={(_, id) => id.toString()}
                   renderItem={({item}) => 
                       <Card 
                           title={item.title}
                           subtitle={item.description}
                           img={item.image}
                       />
                   }
               />
           }
        </View>
```

When it needs to look something like this:

```js
 <View style={styles.container}>
           {loading ? null :
               <FlatList
                   data={[products]}
                   keyExtractor={(_, id) => id.toString()}
                   renderItem={({item}) => 
                       <Card 
                           title={item.title}
                           subtitle={item.description}
                           img={item.image}
                       />
                   }
               />
           }
        </View>
```

Adding that conditional will prevent your Flatlist component from rendering before it has access to the data you are fetching. It looks like you had it right in the original post but not in the Expo Snack environment.

Comment: thanks very much for the help bro its I see the error now thanks again much appreciated.